# How does rhs work?

Tags: c++, overloading

Here I understand rhs means right hand side but I don't understand how does compiler understand "rhs" refers to right hand side. And can someone explain in which case will this overloading be necessary?

```
MyArray<T>& operator=(const MyArray<T>& rhs);
```

Comment: `rhs` is just parameter name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `rhs` stands for "right hand side", and in fact the name of that variable can be anything you like.

The compiler "knows" how to format this because the syntax of `operator=` requires it to be this way.

```
class A
{
public:
   A& operator=(const A& other);
};
```

The language defines the usage of this operator to take the form:

```
A a, b;
a = b;
```

The code above calls `A::operator=(const &other)` against the instance of `A` named `a`, and uses the instance of `A` named `b` as `other`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard assignment operator to an instance of the same type has the prototype

`MyArray<T>& operator=(const MyArray<T>&);`

The name `rhs` is normally given to the function parameter since it appears on the right hand side of an assignment when the operator is invoked. It improves the legibility of your source code, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

`rhs` is just a name people usually use for that operator, it has no special meaning. The way that operator is defined always makes the argument the right-hand element.

Comment: whats the meaning of rhs? I see that it could mean "right hand side" but what actually this means?

Comment: "Right Hand Side" is correct. That's what it means.

Answer (score 2):

If you do something like:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
a = b;
```

The assignment part is actually just a function call:

```
a.operator=(b);
```

Nothing special going on. The parameter name doesn't matter, just the signature which consists of the return type and parameters types, not names.

Answer (score 2):

As with any function, you can call the argument anything that you want.

Using your example with the assignment operator, if you have something like

```
MyArray<int> arr1, arr2;
arr1 = arr2;
```

That is equivalent to

```
MyArray<int> arr1, arr2;
arr1.operator=(arr2);
```

The "right hand side" is simply passed as an argument to a normal member function.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this on this assumption that MyArray will be having some structure like this.

```
    class MyArray{
public:
       int* arr;
       int len;
       MyArray( int l ){
          arr = new int[l];
          len = l;
       }
       ~MyArray(){
          delete [] arr;
       }
    };
```

Now consider a scenario where there are 2 object of MyArray

```
MyArray ob1(3); 
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
   ob1[i]=i*i; // ob1 = {0, 1, 4}
MyArray ob2(3);
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
   ob2[i]=i+1; // ob2 = {1, 2, 3}
```

Now if we do `ob1 = ob2`; what compiler would do it would make arr1 point to arr2, so if Ob2 is changed to say {4,5,6} Ob1 will also change to {4,5,6},  this is called shallow copy.To avoid that scenario we add this

```
MyArray& operator=(const MyArray& rhs){
     for( int i=0; i<rhs.len; i++ ) this.arr[i] = rhs[i];
 }
```

Now if ob2 is changed ob1 will not get affected because we have copied the array on our own not the pointer copy.So this is called deep copy. This is one of major scenario where = is overloaded.